# Why does scaling a column of $U$ by $-1$ make the SVD of a matrix incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Consider the SVD of a matrix $A = U\Sigma V^T$ where $U = [u_1 \; u_2 \; u_3 \; ... \; u_m]$.

If I scale a column of $U$ by $-1$ to, for example, $U^{\prime} = [-u_1 \; u_2 \; u_3 \; ... \; u_m]$, $U^{\prime}$ remains orthogonal and $-u_1$ is still a unit eigenvector of $AA^T$ with the associated eigenvalue $\sigma_1^2$.

However, if I now set $A^{\prime} = U^{\prime}\Sigma V^T$, I get $A \neq A^{\prime}$.

> Why does $U^{\prime}\Sigma V^T$ not give me a valid SVD of $A$?

**Example:**

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1/3 & \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5} & -\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{15}\\ 2/3 & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} & \frac{4\sqrt{5}}{15}\\ -2/3 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}3\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix}1/3 & \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5} & -\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{15}\\ -2/3 & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} & \frac{4\sqrt{5}}{15}\\ 2/3 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}3\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U$ and $V$ cannot be created independently of each other. You cannot simply use *any* $U$ that diagonalizes $AA^T$ and any $V$ that diagonalizes $A^T\!A.$ Calculating an SVD is more than that. $U$ and $V$ must be "compatible".

In your case, you can also scale the first column of $V$ (the first row of $V^T$) to get correct results, again.

However, this is not the only thing that can go wrong. If $AA^T$ and $A^T\!A$ have an eigenvalue $\sigma^2$ with multiplicity greater than $1$, you cannot simply use any set of orthogonal eigenvectors that span the eigenspace of $AA^T$ associated with $\sigma^2$ to fill your $U$ and any set of orthogonal eigenvectors that span the eigenspace of $A^T\!A$ associated with $\sigma^2$ to fill your $V.$ Those basis vectors must also be "compatible".

Comment: If I find $U$ and $V$ independently, is there a way to check for compatibility and alter $U$ and $V$ accordingly? Or must I use the approach of setting $u_i = 1/\sigma_i \times Av_i$?

Comment: I do not know any better way.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
A= \sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_i u_i v_i^\top = \sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_i (-u_i) (-v_i^\top)
\end{align}

You need to also change the sign of the associated right singular vector $v_i$, in your case $v_1$.

Comment: When I compute $U$, I compute orthogonal eigenvectors of $AA^T$. When I compute $V$, I compute orthogonal eigenvectors of $A^TA$. So effectively, I am computing $U$ and $V$ independently. How, would I know whether I also need to scale a column of $V$?

Comment: In general if you use a solver to compute $U$ and $V$, then the software should use a convention on how to order each eigenvector (based on the sign for instance). So if you then change the sign yourself of the first singular vector, you should also change the associated singular vector, as far I am concerned. Also notice that the SVD is unique up to permutation and sign changes.